# UUID vs Hash Field django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to make my primary key look like unrecognized and I found these two solutions. which one is best and why ?

refrences :

hash : https://pypi.org/project/django-hashid-field/

UUID :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/uuidfield-django-models/

Answer (score 1):

Without any metric of what "best" means it's hard to answer, but if your criteria's are

- Must be unique
- Must not follow a clear incrementing pattern

Then I would say go with the [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) as it's an absolutely valid substitute for the [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#autofield) for Primary Key and it's already built into the Django library.

Comment: thanks for comment sir ,  what do you mean by   `Must not follow a clear increment pattern`    .  and is there any drawback to use hashfield ?

Comment: You're welcome. Usually Primary Keys are stored as incremental values such as `1, 2, 3...`. This will gives your models a predictable pattern, and I assumed that you didn't want that. The drawbacks would be that it's not an original Django field, so there might be less support and/or documentation for it whereas the UUIDField is native to Django and guaranteed to work out of the box.

Comment: thanks . got your point . accepting answer